# Functions restricted to $\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y]/(x^2,xy))$ with $k$ algebraically closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Consider functions $g\in k[x,y]$ restricted to $\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y]/(x^2,xy))$ with $k$ algebraically closed.(i.e. $Spec(k[x,y]/(x^2,xy))\subset \operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y])$ allows such restriction.) Denote $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$.

It is easy to check that stalk $R_m$ is nilpotent free if $m=(x,y-b),b\neq 0$.

The book claims that for $g|_m=g(m)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(y-b)\in R_m$ for $m=(x,y-b)$ for $b\neq 0$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why $g|_m$ is determined up to $y-b$ order only here? My though process goes as the following. Since I am localizing away from $(x,y-b)$, certainly $y$ is invertible. So $R_m=(k[x,y]/(x^2,x))_{(x,y-b)}=(k[y])_{y-b}$. However, this says I can determine $g$ up to arbitrary order in $y$ direction.(i.e. I know $\frac{\partial^n g}{\partial y^n}|_{y=b}$ for any $n$.) Is this reasoning wrong here?

Ref. Mumford Algebraic Geometry 2, Chpt 2, Sec 3, Example 2.3.7

Comment: Are you reading this version http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/AGII.pdf ? I don’t see the claim you are asking about in there.

Comment: @Ben See pg 66 pdf Example 3.7 bottom of the page.

Comment: I can’t find the claim about $g|_m$ That you mention

Comment: @Ben Look at pg 66's bottom. "The stalk Oz,Y has no
nilpotents in it except when z = (0, 0). This is an “embedded point”, and if a function g on $A^2_k$ is cut down to Y , $\textbf{the restriction determines both partials of g at (0, 0), but only $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ at other
points}$ (cf. Figure II.4):"

Comment: So you are interpreting this statement as implying the equality you have written down? It doesn't seem to be saying that to me, so maybe you can add why you think that follows from the statement you put in bold?